# Controlling XY Movement by finger dragging in Android

Tags: java, android, touch, andengine

I'm currently making a 2D scrolling shooter game on Android using AndEngine but I'm having an issue with relative touch control which allow player to control the sprite by dragging the finger up/down/left/right to move the ship and the ship should move to the same direction as the finger just like controlling pointer by touchpad (It is pretty common in touchscreen Space Invader-like games nowadays)

So I came up with this code,

```
float oldX, oldY;
float X, Y;
        public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,
                TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {



            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
                float currentX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                float currentY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

                float deltaX = currentX-oldX;
                float deltaY = currentY-oldY;

                System.out.println("X: " + X + " Y: " + Y);

                X= X + deltaX;
                Y= Y + deltaY;

                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The problem that I'm having is that variable X, Y which I'll be using to set the sprite position on the screen isn't increasing/decreasing according to my finger movement, if I continuously dragging my finger right side, the X value should be increasing continuously and when I drag my finger left side, the X value should be decreasing continuously also. But what I'm having is that the X value is increasing/decreasing according to the position of my finger on the screen. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: please clarify - you are dragging across the screen and the position value *is* or *is not* increasing/decreasing?

Comment: Actually it is increasing/decreasing in the direction that I want it to be but as soon as I lifted my finger and start swiping it again in the same direction, the value got changed back and start increasing again as I continue to swipe it until I reach the screen's edge. so I  value around 400 at maximum, I want it to be increasing as long as I keep swiping it in the same direction without the number getting changed back when I lift my finger and continue swiping.

Comment: Actually this is what I'm looking for, I'm just looking for the best way to do the same on Android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858522/cocos2d-sprite-relative-movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the tablet is not able to combine several sweeps. A horizontal sweep is generally a gesture, not a movement.

I think you should set the position of the pointer when you stop sweeping, so you can start fresh with a new sweep.

Please also take a look at Gestures in Android:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/
http://www.anddev.org/gesturedetector_and_gesturedetectorongesturelistener-t3204.html

there is a method onScroll(args) in OnGestureListener, that might help you and save time.